# Selecting records from DB with Zend using distinct but two fields

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I need to select two fields from a table (with Zend 1.12) -- id and sender name -- from a database, but I want to select only the unique sender names as many of them are duplicated.  Here is my code:

```
$objSelect = $db->select()
            ->distinct()
            ->from('tbl_sc_invites', array('id', 'sender_name'), 'sender_name')
            ->order('sender_name ASC')
;
```

But I get the error `Mysqli prepare error: Table 'sender_name.tbl_sc_invites' doesn't exist`

How do I do that? I need to have both `id` and `sender_name` returned from the database so I can create a dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$objSelect = $db->select()
        ->distinct()
        ->from('tbl_sc_invites', array('id', 'sender_name'))
        ->order('sender_name ASC');
```

Otherwise if you don't care about which id you get back you could use GROUP BY

```
$objSelect = $db->select()
        ->distinct()
        ->from('tbl_sc_invites', array('id', 'sender_name'))
        ->order('sender_name ASC')
        ->group('sender_name');
```

Comment: That retrieves duplicates

Comment: Check the updated post with the group. That will only give back 1 id. I don't see why you need the id column though if you only want 1 sender_name. There could be one sender_name with multiple different ids correct?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that there is a problem with using group.  Looks like I need to re-evalutate things.

Comment: I need to retrieve all of the invites for a particular sender.